# How to generate documentation file(pdf or doc) using Compodoc?

Tags: angular, documentation, compodoc

I am using Compodoc for documentation my Angular application

How to generate documentation file(pdf or doc) using Compodoc

Comment: I dont see any reference to pdf or doc renderer on its github or documentation so i asume its not posible with this tool maybe you needs some other tool that converts html to pdf after compodocs creates its html structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **PDF** file export from **Compodoc** is not possible at the moment, but this is planned in a future update.

*Source : https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/190*